# Terminating a protected antivirus process

Tags: c++, security, winapi, kernel, driver

I am using the ESet antivirus, and recently its GUI front-end egui.exe hung and was taking 50% CPU (i.e. 100% of one core). Amazingly, I found that I cannot kill it, even with debug privilege enabled.

Now I am curious: how do they implement such defense, and is there a way to kill it short of writing a kernel driver?

The egui.exe process runs under a regular user (non-admin), and I try to kill it in various ways using an administrative account. Here's what I tried.

- you cannot kill it from task manager
- you cannot kill it using pskill
- you cannot kill it using process explorer, nor can you attach a debugger to it

Then I started some programming and found that:

- under non-privileged user you can open it with PROSESS_TERMINATE access, but actual call to TerminateProcess() fails with error 5.
- under admin account you can open it with any access rights you want (after enabling debug privilege of course), but then calls to TerminateProcess(), GetKernelObjectSecurity(), SetKernelObjectSecurity() all fail with error 5.

This definitely points to some kind of fiddling beyond just setting the process DACL, since if Terminate were not in the DACL, you would not be able to open the process with PROCESS_TERMINATE right in the first place. Are they actually intercepting Win32 API calls? If yes, then how? It's been a while since I did low level system programming, so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Why would you want to know that? :)

Comment: AVs typically do have kernel-mode components. If you could kill it just by giving yourself highest privileges, it would be lousy protection.

Comment: Can you kill it when it runs normally, or is it just when it hung that you cannot kill it ?

Comment: @Cicada: maybe it's me, but I don't like immortal processes that eat up all my CPU

Comment: @nos: I could not kill when it runs normally

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: I am an admin on the machine. I can stop and even uninstall the whole thing. But that's not the point, I curious HOW they do it.

Comment: @IvanKrivyakov: It's not about what user can do, it's about what software can do.

Comment: Also, you can use Process Hacker at processhacker.sourceforge.net to kill the process. Run it as administrator, right-click the process, Terminate. It's open source, so you can see the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can get a hold of the "System Virginity Verifier" from Joanna Rutkowska, this should give you a pretty good idea *where* they implement their hooks. Similar tools (including [GMER](http://www.gmer.net/)) can be used to investigate what's going on in the bowels of the system. It may sound odd, but sometimes AVs use techniques also commonly found in malicious software, i.e. rootkit techniques, in an attempt to protect their software from being fooled.

It sounds like SSDT-Hooking and similar techniques have been used to "protect" the process. My first shot at this would be to suspend all threads of the process. Most such protection mechanisms (of malware and anti-malware alike) trigger only on termination attempts. But once you suspend all the threads (Process Explorer can do that) none of them will be scheduled anymore by the scheduler (leading to no CPU usage).

SSDT (sometimes SDT) stands for System Service Descriptor Table. It's the table with function addresses of the system services (the number of the system service being the index). When you call something like `CreateFile` from your Win32 application it will end up in NTDLL calling [`NtCreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432380.aspx) (== `ZwCreateFile` in UM). From there the mechanism (which has changed since Windows 2000/XP) will differ in how it transitions into kernel mode (KM), aka "ring 0". Anyway, the implementation of `NtCreateFile` in NTDLL roughly does the following: it moves the index of the system service into a register and then invokes the method that is used to transition to KM (`sysenter` opcode in newer implementations). Arriving in KM, the handler will check the index, figure out the function address from the SSDT and then call that function. There is some more checking of the UM stack going on here (when you come from UM), but this is the process in simple terms. So when you hook functionality at this level, you can prevent any subsystem, including the Win32 subsystem from doing things. However, this has several problems attached (yours being the least of them). Most implementers do a bad job, which can be often seen in malware, such as the rootkit Sony chose to put on some audio CDs back in 2005. So unhooking is virtually impossible without risking a bug check and several independent pieces of code hooking the same SSDT index will also usually lead to problems due to recklessness on part of the implementers.

So suspending the threads seems a possibility, although this question of course is kind of open-ended (without knowing the details of the ESET driver(s)). If, however, they prevent that as well you should indeed consider switching products. I wager that disadvantages to system stability of such products outweigh the additional "protection" although they (ESET) are going to tell you otherwise.

Another possible method could be to inject code (e.g. via a DLL) and have the process itself call `ExitProcess`. This also depends on whether or not their hooks allow for this loophole.

Comment: Thanks! I tried suspending the threads (and the process as whole) in Process Explorer, that is disabled too. I can, however, give it an Idle priority. I will check out the tools you mentioned: I did not know about the SSDT-hooking, I think this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think I remember reading somewhere that you can't modify the SSDT in Vista/W7 anymore: you get a bluescreen.

Comment: @Cicada: not entirely true, but yes there is a mechanism called Patchguard, most notably in the x64 versions. There are ways to get around this, and even more so there is a way for ISVs to do things that you normally can't do as "mere mortal". Authentium found a way around Patchguard in the times of Vista still, which apparently prompted MS to create other ways for ISVs.

Comment: SSDT-hooking does not work since Windows XP 64 bit (Windows 2003 Server) because of patch guard 1. If you circumvent patchguard you may be able to hook the ssdt.

Answer (score 1):

There can be different cases, say:

1. If a child thread of the process you are trying to kill is waiting on some kernel object, it will not be terminated until the wait has completed. This can cause the application to stop responding. Any threads in the process are marked for termination - it's one of the process termination steps;
2. Such intelligent software as firewalls, AV and other security-related stuff always installs kernel hooks (aka hooking - intercepting API calls, messages or events passed between kernel objects or software component). They always have a shield to protect agaist the external forces.

You are receiving ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. I do not know what steps you walked through, but may I suggest this:

1. Open Task Manager and go to the Processes Tab;
2. Right click on egui.exe and click on Properties;
3. Click on the Security tab and then click on Edit.
4. On the Permissions window check your credentials;
5. Add a user and/or set the full permissions.

You can play around it, because even when you strat your app (that's what you tried to do, I presume)  it will use your account's credentials.

Comment: How do they install kernel hooks? What keywords to look for?

As for the rest of your suggestions: it's Windows XP, no "security" in task manager. Process Explorer does show a list of groups with "MANDATORY" flag next to each, but that's read-only and I am not sure what that means. My attempts at reading the DACL for the process fail, so I don't see why theirs will be more successful :) I have multiple accounts on the machine, the "terminator" app I wrote runs under the admin account, otherwise, for example, I would not be able to set SeDebugPrivilege.

Comment: You may try this: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx)